# Unknow HTML date format "1615856400000" = "Thuesday, Mar 16, 2021", "1615770000" = "Thuesday, Mar 15, 2021" etc

Tags: html, date, datetime, web-scraping, tags

I'm web scraping a HTML page which shows a time series generated by a function inside a  `<script>` tag. On the webbpage I can see different dates for the time series, but when I "view page source" these dates seem to be converted into numbers.

For example "1615856400000" = "Thuesday, Mar 16, 2021", "1615770000" = "Monday, Mar 15, 2021" and "1612227600000" = "Thuesday, Feb 2, 2021".

Does anyone know what the logic is for these conversions? Ideally I would like a list which shows the mappings per day, starting at some arbitrary date e.g. "Wednesday, Feb 26, 2014".

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Thank you. Will try to find a converter in Python.

Comment: `datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=timezone.utc)`  https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html